# Python: Copy text from notepad, then paste into a specific box in a webpage?

Tags: python

As stated in the title I'm looking to create a python script of sorts that will copy text (up to about 1000 lines) from notepad and then paste into a text box in a webpage and then there is also another clickable box next to the textbox in the webpage which will "submit" what has been pasted, and then repeat this process until the notepad text ends?

Comment: I would go with something like autohotkey.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the question - do you want ALL of the text in the notepad document copied to the text box, then submitted all at once?  Or is there some reason you want the process to repeat?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the `keyboard` library: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

You could use this library to move your mouse and click on the things you want.

It might be easier to use something like the `selenium` library to interact with webpages, and use Python's builtin file reader to read files.